# Ternary Operator in ReactJs Card Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, conditional-operator

How can i put a ternary operator in the title of CardHeader in ReactJS? I can only put one the first Name but not the last name.

```
<CardHeader title={(firstName ? firstName : "")(lastName ? lastName : "")} />;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple ternary operator in the same string:

```
<CardHeader title={`${(firstName ? firstName : "")} ${(lastName ? lastName : "")}`} />
```

In your case i would use a function to generate the full name:

```
const getFullName = () => {
    const name = []
    if(firstName) name.push(firstName)
    if(lastName) name.push(lastName)
    return name.join(' ')
}
// ...
<CardHeader title={getFullName()} />
```

Comment: I don't get it why a downvote.. The answer is correct, and does work perfectly.

Comment: I didnt downvote you. I dont know who downvoted you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to do something like that.

```js
<CardHeader title={`${firstName || ''} ${lastName || ''}`} />;
```